# Ansible: Unable to run docker compose in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, docker-compose

I appear to be unable to run docker compose tasks in an ansible playbook. I get stuck in a loop.

The first error I get when running `sudo ansible-playbook playbook.yml` is the following

```
fatal: [10.0.3.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: No module named compose"}
```

so I remote to that machine and did `sudo pip install docker-compose` and try running the playbook again. This time I get...

```
fatal: [10.0.3.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Cannot have both the docker-py and docker python modules installed together as they use the same namespace and cause a corrupt installation. Please uninstall both packages, and re-install only the docker-py or docker python module"}
```

so I try uninstalling docker python...

- `sudo uninstall docker python`

Then I get the following when attempting to run the playbook again

```
fatal: [10.0.3.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker-py - No module named docker. Try `pip install docker-py`"}
```

However this is already install on the machine, as when I run `sudo pip install docker-py` I see the following...

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docker-py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Does anyone know how to escape this loop and successfully get an ansible playbook that uses docker-compose to run?

The machine os is **linux 14.04**

Thanks,

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant tasks from the Ansible playbook to your question.

Answer (score 38):

What worked for me was to first uninstall everything docker related in the virtualenv for Ansible.

`pip uninstall docker docker-py docker-compose`

And then install the docker-compose module, which will install the `docker` module as well as a dependency.

`pip install docker-compose`

The Ansible docker module will try to `import docker`, which will also succeed with the `docker` module, and as such not provide an error with the misleading instruction to install docker-py.

Comment: I had this issue during AWX installation with docker-compose, this solution helped to resolve this, thanks.

Comment: What do i normally do is install docker using apt-get and install docker-compose using pip. This has solve the problem for me . But some time I have to do the solution mentioned above.

Comment: This saved my long day debugging the issue with awx, many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the just had the same error message while trying to run `sudo ansible playbook-with-docker.yaml`

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: No module named compose"}
```

I took me about 2 hours to figure out that in Linux `pip install` is not the same as `sudo pip install` (quite obvious, once you know what's happening ).

So in case someone has the same issue - make sure you're you are running everything consistently either as `sudo` or not `sudo`, but don't mix stuff :)

...and use `sudo pip list | grep docker` to verify.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in other answers, *docker-compose* python module is missing.
You can install it manually as previous answers indicate or you can use a "pure" *Ansible* solution that is to install via a *task*.

For that, use *ansible.builtin.pip* to install *docker-compose* module (you can add more modules to install if needed in the same task).

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Install docker-compose python package
    ansible.builtin.pip:
      name: docker-compose
```

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html

Answer (score 1):

To add more context to [Thermostat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50491825/10907864)

I was using `pip3` and not `pip` with the following:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Ansible 2.10.7
Python 3.8.10
pip 20.0.2 (pip3)
```

**Here's how I fixed mine**:

So first I ran the command to remove all existing copies of `docker`, `docker-py` and `docker-compose` python libraries:

```
pip3 uninstall docker docker-py docker-compose
```

And then ran the command below to install the **python docker-compose library** alongside the **python docker library**

```
pip3 install docker-compose
```

That's all.