# Error running docker-compose command via Ansible playbook

Tags: macos, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, ansible

I am getting an error trying to execute docker-compose in a ansible playbook.

I am running from a Mac OSX, but the destination node is a AWS ec2 (Ubuntu 20.04)

On Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the following

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install git python3 python3-setuptools 
python3-pip software-properties-common docker docker.io unzip acl -y
sudo apt-add-repository -y --update ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get install ansible -y
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
sudo apt-get install python3-docker
pip3 install docker
pip3 install docker-compose
```

In the main.yml

```
 name: Run "docker-compose up"
  community.docker.docker_compose:
    project_src: /data
    project_name: test
  register: output
```

I am getting the following error

```
fatal: [ndr2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_566twi2g/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 494, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be looking for docker-compose on the AWS host

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: Unable to run docker compose in an ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151210/ansible-unable-to-run-docker-compose-in-an-ansible-playbook)

Comment: I have docker-compse installed. And I seen that answer in that SO question and that didn't work either.

Comment: You bootstrapped the docker compose installation with the Python3 interpreter. Is Ansible executing its provider commands on the remote host with the same Python3 interpreter?

Comment: I believe so, in my hosts file, I have

ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

Comment: I have Python 3.8.9 locally and 3.8.10 on the target server (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 2):

I had to run `sudo apt install docker-compose -y` on the target host, instead of installing docker-compose via pip3. Not sure why it had to be installed this way.